# What's the proper way to use each style in office suites?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, libreoffice

In LibreOffice 3.3, the default range of paragraph styles include the following:

"Addresse, Bibliography, Caption, Complimentary Close, Contents…"

and character styles include:

"Bullets, Definition, Endnote anchor, Example, Footnote anchor…"

Hailing from the HTML authoring realm, I've kind of picked up a habit of making sure everything in a document is styled correctly. The problem is, I don't know what those are and when it is appropriate to use each of them.

Is there an online resource explaining all the styles above, just as how W3C explains the usage of the tags in its HTML specs?

Comment: I would start by checking 
http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Writer/FormattingText/How_do_I_use_styles%3F

Comment: @Dennis The page tells you how to apply styles in the application. Which is good for a beginner to Office apps who's already had prior knowledge about styling (like in, for example, publications). 
But for someone who knows nothing about styles in writing, where can he learn about when to use different heading levels, when to style a span of words as `definition`, etc? It's like owning a tool, knowing how to use it but not where to use it (properly).